# Join rows in one row based on common ID

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have a dataframe with 3 columns: ID, F and M. I want to join the values for F and M into one row based on ID, while now most of them are in two separate rows with NAs instead.

I do have unfortunately some duplicate rows and the data is still a bit messy at the moment (see example below)

I tried this, but I get Error: Expecting a single value: [extent=2].

```
 test2 <- test %>%  mutate(grouped_id = row_number()) %>%
                    group_by(BroodID) %>% 
                    summarise_each(funs(na.omit))
```

Here is a reproducible example of what my data looks like:

```
 structure(list(ID = c(2010.3, 2010.3, 2010.3, 2010.3, 2010.33, 
 2010.34, 2010.38, 2010.38, 2010.39, 2010.39, 2010.4, 2010.4, 
 2010.4, 2010.4, 2010.4, 2010.41, 2010.41, 2010.42, 2010.42, 2010.44, 
 2010.44, 2010.46, 2010.46), F = structure(c(5L, 5L, 12L, 12L, 
 11L, 8L, NA, 3L, NA, 1L, NA, 2L, 2L, 6L, 6L, NA, 7L, NA, 9L, 
 NA, 4L, NA, 10L), .Label = c("T206434", "T206553", "T931169", 
 "T931286", "T961275", "V470937", "X250041", "X250109", "X250195", 
 "X250568", "X251067", "X251069"), class = "factor"), M = structure(c(2L, 
 2L, 11L, 11L, 6L, NA, 9L, NA, 10L, NA, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, NA, 8L, 
 NA, 3L, NA, 7L, NA, 5L, NA), .Label = c("T206824", "T206994", 
"T960191", "T961486", "X250567", "X250779", "X250851", "X251046", 
 "X251066", "X251074", "X251116"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
 23L), class = "data.frame")
```

I'd like the rows where the values for F and M are split into two rows to be merged into one row based on ID.

Answer (score 0):

We could use `unite` with `na.rm = TRUE` to remove `NA` values and use `distinct` to have only `unique` rows.

```
library(dplyr)

test %>%
  mutate_at(2:3, as.character) %>%
  tidyr::unite(combined, F, M, na.rm = TRUE, sep = ",") %>%
  distinct()

#        ID        combined
#1  2010.30 T961275,T206994
#2  2010.30 X251069,X251116
#3  2010.33 X251067,X250779
#4  2010.34         X250109
#5  2010.38         X251066
#6  2010.38         T931169
#7  2010.39         X251074
#8  2010.39         T206434
#9  2010.40         T206824
#10 2010.40 T206553,T206824
#11 2010.40 T206553,T961486
#12 2010.40 V470937,T961486
#13 2010.40         V470937
#14 2010.41         X251046
#15 2010.41         X250041
#16 2010.42         T960191
#17 2010.42         X250195
#18 2010.44         X250851
#19 2010.44         T931286
#20 2010.46         X250567
#21 2010.46         X250568
```

If we want to further summarise by `ID`, we can do

```
test %>%
  mutate_at(2:3, as.character) %>%
  tidyr::unite(combined, F, M, na.rm = TRUE, sep = ",") %>%
  distinct() %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(combined = toString(combined))
```

Comment: that could help, but I just tried it on the same example that I posted here and I get  Error: `TRUE` must evaluate to column positions or names, not a logical vector.

Any idea why that could be?

Comment: @JaneBirkin it works for me though on same data. Can you try adding backquotes to names? `test %>%
  mutate_at(2:3, as.character) %>%
  tidyr::unite(combined, \`F\`,\`M\`, na.rm = TRUE, sep = ",") %>%
  distinct()
`